# understanding if statement

Tags: php

I have few lines of code in a theme, I did not understood, can anyone explain me this.

```
$screen = get_current_screen(); // understood this
if ( $screen && 'post' == $screen->base && 'page' == $screen->id ) { // not sure about this line
// code to execute something
}
```

As per I have understood the code is executed when post type is post or page, I am not sure how, I need to add another custom post type (`player`) in that `if` statement.

Comment: Actually, that conditional means, check if the base of the current file in the URL is `post` and that the post type is `page`. I.e. If you're *editing* a Page, the conditional would return true. If you want to check for another post type, just change the `'page' == $screen->id` to `in_array( $screen->id, [ 'page', 'player', 'etc-cpt' ] )`

Comment: @SallyCJ That sounds like a wonder answer you could post in the answer section below :)

Answer (score 1):

> the code is executed when post type is post or page

No, only if the post type is `page` (because of the `'page' == $screen->id`).

Because that `if` statement actually checks if the current admin screen is the one for *editing or creating* a Page (post type of `page`), where the URL looks like so: (note that the post type is not visible in the URL when a post/Page/CPT is being edited)

`http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit`

- On such screens — *editing or creating* a post/Page/CPT, `$screen->id` is equivalent to `$screen->post_type` which is the post type (slug).
- And `$screen->base` is `post` which is the base name of the file name in the current URL — base name is the file name without the extension — so if the file name is `post.php`, the base name is `post`. However, when *creating* a post/Page/CPT, the file name is actually `post-new.php`, but still the `$screen->base` is `post` (and not `post-new`) because WordPress strips the `-new` part.
- Additionally, you can distinguish between editing and creating by checking the screen's action; i.e. whether `$screen->action` is `edit` or `add` (e.g. `'edit' == $screen->action` to check if the action is *editing*).

[image]

> I need to add another custom post type (`player`) in that `if`
>   statement

Just change the:

```php
'page' == $screen->id
```

to:

```php
in_array( $screen->id, array( 'post', 'page', 'player' ) )
```

Or the full code:

```php
if ( $screen &&                // 1. we've got a valid screen
    'post' == $screen->base && // 2. the screen base is either post.php or post-new.php
    // and 3. the post type is one of the array values.
    in_array( $screen->id, array( 'post', 'page', 'player' ) )
) {
    // your code here
}
```

I hope that helps, and you can check the `get_current_screen()`'s function reference [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/). :)